# Is it possible to add custom calculated row in table?

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

My data source is Excel file. I imported the Excel file in a tableau. I want to create custom calculated row field for each column.

[image]

In the above picture, I can generate Grand Total in tableau from here Analysis -> Totals -> Show column grand totals. My problem is I want to generate another row which will have value from sum of High + medium row values.

Note: I taken this screenshot from excel sheet and please ignore the values in the row.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a calculated field to sum just the High and Low values. Something like:

```
sum(If [Priority] = 'High' or [Priority] = 'Low' then [Value] end)
```